# Rotated text in side margin

Tags: rotating, fancyhdr

I've typeset a very wide table using `longtable` and rotating all the cells. As a consequence, if I want to place a "right" header, it ought to be in the bottom of the right margin, with the text rotated. I've been looking at some combination of `fancyhdr` and `rotating`, but can't get it to work. Rotating the text isn't the problem, but how does one place text at the bottom of a side margin?

Right now I have

```
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\begin{turn}{-90}\parbox{2in}{test \\ line two}\end{turn}}
```

which, of course, doesn't actually end up in the side margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is produce a single page in landscape. I was hoping that the `geometry` package's `\newgeometry` could do this, but it cannot.

I'd guess that the best bet would be to simply make another single page pdf that is in landscape for your table and then use `\includepdf` from [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages).

I guess that one alternative would be to use `\newgeometry` in concert with a single rotation of a `minipage` which contained all of the headers for that page (which you may have to just fill out yourself). Then you rotate the whole minipage and stuff it in the appropriate location. It'd take some fiddling around with though. It's also less attractive if the `fancyhdr` stuff doesn't work and the headers have to be written by hand.

Comment: This is a good idea. It's a table spanning many spages (I'm trying to latex a spreadsheet--yes, it's a bit silly), but reading one page in at a time with pdfpages should do it.

Comment: @hoyland: Well, you can read in an entire range of pages or all of the pages so it doesn't have to be one at a time.

Comment: @TH Yes, you're right--I didn't realise pdfpages could do the rotation itself. It's worked. Thank you very much.