# fancyhdr in page margins

Tags: tikz-pgf, fancyhdr

I want to print text as you would a header on a page but rotated in the left/right margins of the page following a typical book format (print right on odd pages and print left on even pages) using class `book` and package `fancyhdr`.  This includes page numbers.

A previous answer was a good start (found here: [Rotated, running text in right margin?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54808/rotated-running-text-in-right-margin))  and works as posted.  However, it does not seem to work in my MWE.

My MWE produces:

- No text in margin on page 1 (text should be in right margin)
- A centered page number on page 1 (page number should be east)
- Text in margin appears on page 2 (this is correct)
- Page number on page 2 is east (should be west)

Similar issues with pages 3 and 4.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.00in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,calc}

\begin{document}
% PAGE MARGINS HEADER/FOOTER
\fancypagestyle{sideheading}{%
  %% Clear all headers and footers
  \fancyhf{}
    %% Right headers on odd pages
  \fancyhead[RO]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \node[text=black,
      inner ysep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,
      execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{\textheight}},%<====
      execute at end node={\end{varwidth}},
      rotate=-90]
      at ([xshift=-13mm,yshift=0mm]current page.east)
      {\Gid};
    \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        %% Left headers on even pages
\fancyhead[LE]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \node[text=black,
      inner ysep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,
      execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{\textheight}},%<====
      execute at end node={\end{varwidth}},
      rotate=90]
      at ([xshift=13mm,yshift=0mm]current page.west)
      {\Gid};
    \end{tikzpicture}
        }
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}

\newcommand{\Gid}{}

\fancyhf{}
\chead{\Gid} 
\pagestyle{sideheading}
\linespread{0.0}

\renewcommand{\Gid}{{\bf \Large MARGIN TEXT 1}} 

\chapter{Insert Coin(s) To Begin}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols*}

\renewcommand{\Gid}{{\bf \Large MARGIN TEXT 2}} 
\chapter{How To Handle Loss}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. `\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}` types the page number on the right side of the page for even or odd page numbers.  Change this line to

   ```
   \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % <=======================================
   ```
2. You need to define style `plain` too, it is used in chapter pages in class `book`. So copy the complete code of `\fancypagestyle{sideheading}{%` and add it with the changed line `\fancypagestyle{plain}{%`.

Please see the following complete mwe:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{book}

\usepackage[margin=1.00in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,calc}


\begin{document}
% PAGE MARGINS HEADER/FOOTER
\fancypagestyle{sideheading}{%
  %% Clear all headers and footers
  \fancyhf{}
    %% Right headers on odd pages
  \fancyhead[RO]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \node[text=black,
      inner ysep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,
      execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{\textheight}},%<====
      execute at end node={\end{varwidth}},
      rotate=-90]
      at ([xshift=-13mm,yshift=0mm]current page.east)
      {\Gid};
    \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        %% Left headers on even pages
\fancyhead[LE]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \node[text=black,
      inner ysep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,
      execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{\textheight}},%<====
      execute at end node={\end{varwidth}},
      rotate=90]
      at ([xshift=13mm,yshift=0mm]current page.west)
      {\Gid};
    \end{tikzpicture}
        }
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % <=======================================
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% <==============================================
  %% Clear all headers and footers
  \fancyhf{}
    %% Right headers on odd pages
  \fancyhead[RO]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \node[text=black,
      inner ysep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,
      execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{\textheight}},%<====
      execute at end node={\end{varwidth}},
      rotate=-90]
      at ([xshift=-13mm,yshift=0mm]current page.east)
      {\Gid};
    \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        %% Left headers on even pages
\fancyhead[LE]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \node[text=black,
      inner ysep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,
      execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{\textheight}},%<====
      execute at end node={\end{varwidth}},
      rotate=90]
      at ([xshift=13mm,yshift=0mm]current page.west)
      {\Gid};
    \end{tikzpicture}
        }
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % <=======================================
}

\newcommand{\Gid}{}

\fancyhf{}
\chead{\Gid} 
\pagestyle{sideheading}
\linespread{0.0}

\renewcommand{\Gid}{{\bf \Large MARGIN TEXT 1}} 

\chapter{Insert Coin(s) To Begin}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols*}

\renewcommand{\Gid}{{\bf \Large MARGIN TEXT 2}} 
\chapter{How To Handle Loss}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

and the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting page 1]

and page two:

[image: resulting page two]

Answer (score 2):

Chapter pages use pagestyle `plain` by default. If `plain` should use the same settings as a previous set fancy page style, you can redefine `plain` using

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
```

If you use `\pagestyle{sidemargin}` *before* the first `\thispagestyle{plain}` or `\pagestyle{plain}` plain pages will get the same headers and footers.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.00in,showframe,
  headheight=13.6pt% as suggested by fancyhdr
]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,calc}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{}% <- added
\fancypagestyle{sideheading}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[RO]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \node[text=black,
      inner ysep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,
      execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{\textheight}},
      execute at end node={\end{varwidth}},
      rotate=-90]
      at ([xshift=-13mm,yshift=0mm]current page.east)
      {\Gid};
    \end{tikzpicture}
        }
\fancyhead[LE]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \node[text=black,
      inner ysep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,
      execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{\textheight}},
      execute at end node={\end{varwidth}},
      rotate=90]
      at ([xshift=13mm,yshift=0mm]current page.west)
      {\Gid};
    \end{tikzpicture}
        }
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}% <- changed
}

\newcommand{\Gid}{}
%\fancyhf{}% not needed
%\chead{\Gid}% not needed
\pagestyle{sideheading}
\begin{document}
\linespread{0.0}

\renewcommand{\Gid}{{\bfseries \Large MARGIN TEXT 1}} 
\chapter{Insert Coin(s) To Begin}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols*}

\renewcommand{\Gid}{{\bfseries \Large MARGIN TEXT 2}} 
\chapter{How To Handle Loss}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]